# node acl allow permissions

Tags: node.js, acl, node-acl

I'm using `node_acl` for authorization of my webapp. I want my admin to have access to all the routes, so I have declared acl permissions as below:

```
acl.allow([
    {
      roles: 'admin',
      allows: [
        { resources: '*', permissions: '*' }
      ]
    },  
    {
      roles: 'guest',
      allows: [
        { resources: '/documentation', permissions: ['get'] }
      ]
    }
]);
```

I have used `acl.addUserRoles` to set the role of users but when I tried to make any request using admin user, `acl.isAllowed` returns `false` and `acl.allowedPermissions` of the user returns `{ routeName: [] }`.

Is there something wrong with my `acl.allow` permissions ?